# Multiple types of build for different build triggers

Tags: teamcity

I have a setup where our code builds to dev every 5 hours on a schedule trigger. This works great, but the downside that the code could sit in teamcity for hours before it triggers and alerts us to a build error.

Is there a way to have a VCS trigger also run the build as soon as its checked in, but passing something to our NANT script to say "just build, don't deploy"?

I know I must be missing something.. is there any way to achieve this?
The only way I could think of was to have an entirely separate build configuration, but that seemed rather wasteful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a new build with a VCS trigger and then have that build have a env/system variable set that your build script can read to determine whether or not to deploy to dev.

See [TeamCity Docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration) for information around this. I've used something like this in setting up builds before and it works well.

Comment: I was messing around with meta-runners, and realised when I referenced my build's metarunner, there are dropdowns for all the build parameters. So this achieves what I want, but without duplicating the build configuration